# pageViewController.view.transform called simultaneously with .setViewControllers causes a visual glitch in the animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uipageviewcontroller

I resumed an old project of mine in which I was trying to achieve a book flipping animation while the book translates on the x axis. This was achieved as explained below.

In `viewDidLoad()` I declared the `pageViewController` as follows, with `.pageCurl` as the transition style:

```
    pageController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .pageCurl, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
    pageController?.setViewControllers([UIViewController()], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The spine is set to be `.mid` in the DataSource protocol, that's the reason of the generic `UIViewController()`.

Then, in `viewDidAppear()`, I performed both the translation tapping into the `.transform` property and the flipping animation through `.setViewControllers()`.

```
override internal func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.5) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, animations: {
            self.pageController?.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: self.view.bounds.width/4, y: 0)
        }, completion: nil)
        self.pageController?.setViewControllers(self.startingPages, direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Although maybe not pretty, this did the job almost two years ago, so Xcode 12.5, Swift 5.4 and testing on iOS 14.5.
[The final effect was this.](https://streamable.com/9glv2d)

Testing again now on iOS 16.1.1, with Xcode 14.2, [this is the result.](https://streamable.com/lpi43j)
Apparently the same identical code causes now a visual glitch, as the cover page of the book simply freezes and don't flip/translate. This happens just like 80% of the times, not always, otherwise the animations are fine. Also, occasionally it gives me a crash in the app.

Do anyone knows what's the issue and how to solve this?

Comment: I get this error for the videos: "This video has been archived and is not available to watch at this time."